# Dragging a sprite with TouchMoved

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, drag, freeze, sprite, touchmove

I'm using Xcode with Cocos2d version 3.0.

I want to drag sprites around the screen. I've done so successfully using the following code:

```
(void) touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 

{

CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

sprite1.position=touchLocation; 

sprite2.position=touchLocation; 

sprite3.position=touchLocation;

sprite4.position=touchLocation; 

}
```

However, sometimes the sprites stop moving after a second. It's not a lag, because they never catch back up with my movement. They just stop! If I let go and start moving my touch again, the sprites start moving fine again / sometimes do the 'freeze thing' again.

Is it a memory issue?

Ok, I'm sure it must be memory. I copied this code onto a simple game with hardly any sprites and it worked perfectly.

Comment: maybe the touch leaves [self boundingBox], in which case you will stop receiving the touchmoved events.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yves. I think the 'self' refers to the whole screen. Of course my finger doesn't leave the screen. Maybe I should change the 'self' to something else?

Comment: I dont play darts :)  ... if you "know" that self's bounding box is the full screen, then you are right and i have no further explanation to offer. luck

Comment: What happens if you touch the screen with two fingers? Are the positions maybe fighting between *any* touch?

Comment: 2 fingers has no effect :/
It seems like the game stops reading the movement every now and then...I think that's the best way I can describe it.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure it must be memory. I copied this code onto a simple game with hardly any sprites and it worked perfectly. Gosh darn it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got it!

I had to unEnable the UISwipeGestureRecognizers while I moved the sprite.

The game was registering my touchesMoved movement as a swipe, and cancelling the touchesMoved commands.